# how to not use default field separator in AWK

Tags: awk

I have a string like this:

```
tony x25 xdata engineer Xhome
```

and i want to use awk to split this string with `x` or `X`,

```
awk '{FS="[xX]"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' 1
```

but the result is like this:

```
tony
x25
xdata
engineer
Xhome
```

Seems the default field separator of whitespace is still used, how to not use default field separator but only character `x` or `X` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your code into:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS="[xX]"} {for.....
```

or

```
 awk -F"[xX]" '{for(....
```

#### some detail:

If you don't put the `FS` in `BEGIN` block, when awk gets the first line, the default `FS` was used, that's why you got the output in your question. However, after the first line, the `FS` was set by `[Xx]`, that is, from the 2nd line in your file, the fields would be separated by `[Xx]`.  Unfortunately, your input example has only one line. You can add some more lines to test.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the record separator `RS` instead of the the field separotor `FS`:

```
$ awk -v RS='[Xx]' 1 <<< "tony x25 xdata engineer Xhome"
tony
25
data engineer
home
```

Setting `RS` to the regex `[Xx]` allows to cut the string in pieces. These ones are printed using the output record separator `ORS` that is by default set to `\n`.

Comment: No, that's not the problem and only gawk allows a multi-char RS so you'd be making the script non-portable for no good reason.

Comment: @EdMorton While I agree your remark about multi-char RS limitation. If OP is using gawk, I do feel that setting RS is more powerful than setting FS and looping through all elements. In that sense I think this answer is addressing OP's issue.

Comment: Depends whether or not the OP wants his final output value to be `home\n`. If he does then setting RS to `[xX]` as in your script would be correct, To get the output the OP **seems** to be expecting by setting RS instead of FS you'd have to write `awk -v RS='[Xx\n]' 'RT!=""'` or `awk -v RS='[xX]' '{sub(/\n$/,"")} 1'` or similar and if there's multiple input lines to be processed one line at a time you'd have to add logic to handle that too. That all might be exactly what the OP wants, of course, idk.